# Binding style gives error

Tags: wpf

I have written code to attach a property Mask.But iam getting the error

Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Marsk'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.)

```
public static MaskType GetMask(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (MaskType)obj.GetValue(MaskProperty);
}

public static void SetMask(DependencyObject obj, MaskType value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MaskProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Mask",
        typeof(MaskType),
        typeof(pMaskableTextBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MaskChangedCallback)
        );

private static void MaskChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldValue is TextBox)
    {
        (e.OldValue as TextBox).PreviewTextInput -= TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler((e.OldValue as TextBox), (DataObjectPastingEventHandler)TextBoxPastingEventHandler);
    }

    TextBox _this = (d as TextBox);
    if (_this == null)
        return;

    if ((MaskType)e.NewValue != MaskType.Any)
    {
        _this.PreviewTextInput += TextBox_PreviewTextInput;
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(_this, (DataObjectPastingEventHandler)TextBoxPastingEventHandler);
    }

    ValidateTextBox(_this);
}
```

i have called this property in styles rStyles.XAML

```
xmlns:pBasePage="clr-namespace:Parts.Pages.Page;assembly=Parts.Pages.Page"

<Style x:Key="styDecimalTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="pBasePage:Parts.Pages.Page.pMaskableTextBox.Mask" Value ="Decimal"  />
</Style>
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="pBasePage:pMaskableTextBox.Mask" Value ="Decimal"  />` Try this...

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all really:

> Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Mask'. Verify that the owning type
>   is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the
>   Property.)

Check the TargetType:

```
<Style x:Key="styDecimalTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type YourTextBoxWithTheMaskProperty}">
    <Setter Property="pBasePage:Parts.Pages.Page.pMaskableTextBox.Mask" Value ="Decimal"  />
</Style>
```